# Trying to join a Domain on WinServer 2008R2 but can't start "Workstation service" because of Error 1075

Tags: azure, active-directory, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008

I just made a VM from the "[smalldisk] Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1" image on Azure. I am trying to join my (running and working) Domain in the same VPN but when I open the Name/Domain Options it says I can't join a domain until I have started the Workstation Service.

Trying to start the workstation service I get the following error:

> Windows could not start the Workstation service on Local Computer.
>   Error 1075: The dependency service does not exist or has been market for deletion.

Obviously I googled the error but mostly people seem to have that error because they're using some kind of Disk Compatibility mode and recommend changing it in the BIOS. This being a VM I don't really have access to the BIOS.

Anyone ever ran into this problem? How do I get around it?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue.

In the event log the following error is shown:
Log Name:      System
Source:        Service Control Manager
Date:          25/01/2018 16:50:54
Event ID:      7003
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      MYSERVERNAME
Description:
The Workstation service depends the following service: bowsemb20. This service might not be installed.

On review the dependencies for the workstation service the following registry key was set to:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanWorkstation --> DependsOnService =
 bowsemb20
 NSI

This was changed to match an existing server:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\LanmanWorkstation  --> DependsOnService =
 Bowser
 MRxSmb20
 NSI

After a reboot the service started and the server joined the domain without an issue.

SMB 1.0 is no longer installed by default on Azure images.
Looks like Microsoft has not tested the latest Windows 2008 R2 Azure Image before making it available to the public.
This will be affecting a wider public.

Comment: I did some more googling and found another solution that proposes to delete the key for DependsOnService.
I did so and now I get "Error 2: File not found" :/

Comment: Damn, I tried your solution butapparently  Bowser MRxSmb20 NSI  isn't there either?

Comment: My suggestion was to match the details from an existing server in your domain.

"This was changed to match an existing server: "

Comment: Ah, I misread it as existing service.
Now I just need to find a working 2008 server ^^

Comment: Using '2.127.20171115' version of the '2008-R2-SP1' Azure VM image also resolved this issue.

'2.127.20171217' which is the current latest one has issue adding to domain.

Comment: I modified the value of `DependsOnService` to `Bowser MRxSmb20 NSI` and it works! Microsoft QAs didn't do a great job...

Comment: Hey there, just to say this worked for me. Not sure if you are still in SO, but five years later this is still helping people! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The following line should fix the service:

```
sc config lanmanworkstation depend = nsi/bowser/mrxsmb20
```